# isShowing() vs isDisplayable()

Tags: java, performance

What is better to use:

```
.isDisplayable()
```

or:

```
isShowing()
```

to check if JButtons are visible, but also for other things? Also what is the difference between them? At this moment they look like same thing to me, but i'm a beginner.

Comment: There is no *better* and instead it all depends on the situation. Have you looked at the [Component API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) for the differences? The link will tell you exactly what the methods are for. Please read this first before asking, if only to help make your question more specific to exactly what confuses you.

Comment: I know what they are for. I tried to use them both in my code inside IF but they are giving same results (even when button was set to Opaque(false) ) My question is not about what they are for. It's about what is better to use.

Comment: The point that Hovercraft is making is that your question is akin to asking "Which is better to use? Subtraction or while loops?" They serve different purposes; it's just not a valid comparison.

Comment: @Mariusz, `even when button was set to Opaque(false)` - opaqueness if for painting the background of the component. The component can still be visible (because it is added to a visible GUI) even if the background is transparent. Try using setVisible(false) to see the difference. `but i'm a beginner.` - I have never used those methods. Why do you thing you need to use them. What is your requirement? What problem are you trying to solve.

Comment: @camickr you could put this as answer, isShowing returns false when JButton is set to Visible(false);  this is main difference between them. Question to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

> they are giving same results, even when button was set to Opaque(false)

Don't confuse opaqueness of a component with visibility of a component.

Opaqueness is for painting the background of the component.

The component can still be visible even if the background is transparent.

Try using `setVisible(false)` to see the difference between the two methods.

A component can only be showing if it is:

1. displayable
2. visible